# How does hibernate manage collections (Insert, Update, Remove )?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

### Describtion

Im running into a issue where hibernate inserts childs every single time their parent gets updated. This results in this issue : [Copied parent inserts childs instead of updating them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731215/copied-parent-inserts-childs-instead-of-updating-them)

I havent found any informations about this... so im breaking this issue down.

### Question

When and how does hibernate decide if a child needs to get inserted into a relation ?
When does it insert a parents child, when does it remove them and when does it update ?
And how can we effect this behaviour ? Are there tricks ?
How can we force hibernate to updata a child, to ignore it or to remove it instead of inserting it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Hibernate relies on a snapshot state and if that doesn't exist for the current session, it will select/fetch the collection first and then compute the diff. There is not much you can configure or affect there, this is a Hibernate primitive.